# Cannot Upload C++ extension to Colab

Tags: linux, python-3.x, c++11, google-colaboratory, pybind11

I wrote a C++ extension and wrapped it using PyBind11 and compiled it on my Linux machine which yielded a .so file that works locally; however, I cannot upload that .so file to Colab so I tried it on Windows and got a .pyd file which does not upload either... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong, but what method do you think that colab provides to upload system libraries? (hint: none).

You may have better luck trying to embed C code into python, i.e scipy.weave, but that still requires an environment that has access to a C compiler, which colab does not provide.

You can test if weave is provided as part of a jupyter environment as follows:

```
!pip install -q weave

import weave
weave.test()
```

Comment: when I **!pip install -q weave** I get the following error: ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-h5b3e1jh/weave/

Comment: @Griffy: Per the 2nd paragraph, google colab does not provide a C compiler which is required to compile C code.

Comment: If your Colab machine is Linux-based, you can probably install your own C compiler through `apt`? Installing deps through `apt` has been done through this course's tutorial notebook: [RussTedrake/underactuated/mathematical_program.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/src/mathematical_program_examples.ipynb#scrollTo=W4w1m572eYZ-)

Comment: the above Russ Tedrake link no longer active.